# Atmosphere broadcast from outside as a guest

Tags: gwt, websocket, atmosphere

Actually i did a basic websocket client<-->server.
But i cant handle something : how can my server can send a broatcast ?
I would like to call a service and it will call atmosphere to post the data i want.

Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking how to send a broadcast message to all clients, based on theirs documentation, the way to broadcast all resources should be this:

```
  Future<Object> f = BroadcasterFactory.getDefault().lookup("/*").broadcast("Hello");
  try {
    f.get();
  } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (ExecutionException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

Obiously, you can create more broadcasters with different names and assign them to different resources. Then from any service you could use the `BroadcasterFactory` to get the appropriate broadcaster to send a message to certain clients.